Manhua where fl transmigrates into a game where she is very wealthy and tries to stop end of world
The female lead has pink hair with blue ends and everything in the world is somewhat food related. I’m pretty sure there is an earl grey kingdom or something. She goes into a game she had played and invested a lot of money in while trying to beat the boss character. The game was really glitchy and didn’t work well. She gets transmigrated and decides to go to school with the villain boss and tries to befriend him. That doesn’t work well so she tries to befriend a power light based character who she invests in helping to build her abilities. She later creates a club dedicated to helping people grow their abilities secretly and calls it the photosynthesis club. I remember there is a half cat dude too. I’ve been looking for this manhua for a while now and can’t remember its name or find it anywhere

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you read this?

This is probably Cashman of a Ruined Game:

I fell into a ruined game as a full-leveled main character with S-class equipment, and an inventory filled with miscellaneous items. To save this game–no, this world–I have to *stop the final boss who will destroy everything. Let’s go to the Imperial Academy of Magic! With my young, rich, and pretty charm, I’ll roast him, boil him, and lead him to the right path!

The main character has pink hair with blue ends:

In chapter 19 she decides to create a club in order not to be forced to join someone else's club:

